# Users can send non-valid bets on my site with the console

Tags: javascript, html, console, userscripts

I have a website where users can bet on specified coin they think it will win.
I have TT(1-7), CT(8-14) and DRAGON(0). Pretty roulette-based.
So, basically, users on my site can right click > inspect element > console and paste this command: `send({"type" : "bet", "amount": "1e+2", "lower": 1, "upper" : 7, "round" : ROUND});` 
This command will bet amount `1e+2` (which is not valid) on TT which is (1-7), on execute.
Website will display that the bet only `1` credit, but they actually really put literally `1e+2` amount. Also, if they win, they are getting like 15000+ credits, insead of 2, because TT and CT coins just double your bet amount, while DRAGON do 14x.
Is there any way to disable console, disable console input, or something like that? I know its fixable, just not sure on which way.

Edit: additional informations: 
when user try to bet `1e+2` amount on valid-way, with the input box on my site, it will say it's not valid amount, but for console its not working. Also, its not just `1e+2` they can do like `2e+51` or just some random numbers and signs.

Comment: You can't disable the console.

Comment: hmm im pretty sure its fixable, just dont know on which way.

Comment: You can never trust anything that originates from a client & you can never make a client trustworthy. You should be running whatever checks are needed on the server and deciding if the request is legitimate there.

Comment: Well, Server checks valid-way bets, but no idea how can I make it check console-sided bets.

Comment: If you don't know how to get your server to check those bets, you need to hire a programmer who does.  **It is impossible to stop the user from submitting invalid/fraudulent data to your server.**  Your server must be alert for such data.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check on the server whether a sent request is valid. Always assume that every client tries to attack you. Client-sided inputs can be changed very easily.

EDIT: In PHP, you can validate the input like this:

```
if(preg_match("[0-9]", $sent_input) {
    // valid input, execute the code
} else {
    die("Invalid input");
}
```

Comment: Any way you can help me out with that? Not sure how should I do that for client console.

Comment: If you explain, why certain inputs aren't valid or what makes an input valid, yes.

Comment: Input is valid when there is only numbers in it, 
Input is invalid if Input contains something else than number, example: signs like !@#%&*(.... or even letters like awqrtyuiplapbkata ......

Comment: You can use regex to validate the sent input in the backend. You are using PHP I assume? I will add a little explanation on how to do it there to the answer.

Comment: yeah Im using php.

Comment: It's not working, users can still use console to bet invalid amounts.

Comment: Could you provide parts of the PHP code?

Comment: Ouh, my bad. Im not using PHP for bads, Im using combination of javascript php and a lot of modules. I didnt make that script so its a little bit hard for me to find exact code affiliated with bets.

Comment: Then, can you provide what modules you are talking about?

Comment: I think this is what you are asking for. `https://pastebin.com/9Ff4kvYG`